# C++ - Ler o nome dos arquivos de um diretório

Tags: c++, sistema-de-arquivos, c++11

Eu estou fazendo um programa para ler todos os arquivos de uma pasta, e limpar o nome dos mesmos ( tirar qualquer acento ).

Gostaria de saber se existe uma biblioteca padrão para trabalhar com diretórios(Ler). Estou utilizando Windows 10, Visual Code com MinGW.

O único exemplo que me atendeu parcialmente é:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <dirent.h>

int main (void)
{
  DIR *dp;
  struct dirent *ep;

  dp = opendir ("./");
  if (dp != NULL)
    {
      while (ep = readdir (dp))
        puts (ep->d_name);
      (void) closedir (dp);
    }
  else{
    perror ("Couldn't open the directory");
  }  
  system("pause");
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Você pode utilizar da biblioteca *Boost* o componente *filesystem* exemplo:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/filesystem.hpp>
using namespace boost::filesystem;

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
   path Desktop("C://Desktop");
   recursive_directory_iterator end;

   for(recursive_directory_iterator i(Desktop); i != end; ++i)
   {
       path file_name = *i;
       std::cout << file_name.string() << std::endl;
   }
   return 0;
}
```

https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_71_0/libs/filesystem/doc/index.htm